# Surge arrester placement in substation

Tags: surge-protection, distribution-network

Is it enough to place surge arrester on the terminals of the transformer in a substation, or every power line entering the substation should have its own?

Comment: Depends, I'd guess? What are you protecting against what? How much risk do you model?

Comment: @MarcusMüller the substation is a part of high voltage transmission system, with two 220/110 kV/kV transformers

Comment: yeah, that's what substations do. So, what do you plan to protect against what risk? Where in your network does the surge potentially come from?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm planning to protect the transformers from overvoltages caused by lightning and switching, so I wanted to place one surge arrester on HV side and one on the LV side. I don't know the configuration of the network around the substation, just the fact that 3 power lines are entering the HV side, and 4 leaving the LV side.

Comment: so, but maybe you know whether the LV or HV side are buried or overland lines? Because that helps decide which side might get struck by lightning. If you can't say anything, and if the arrestors are cheap enough – of course, go for maximum protection. As you can see, this problem is defined by the circumstances, both of a technical and an economical nature!

Comment: @MarcusMüller both, the HV and LV side are overhead lines.

Comment: so, now you apply your knowledge of what you want to protect with that information and use logic to deduct! You're already answering your own question.

Comment: @MarcusMüller So, both the HV and LV side are overhead lines, so they can both be struck by lightning, meaning the overvoltage can enter the substation from both the HV and the LV side, meaning we need surge arresters from both sides of the transformer. If I want to protect the equipment on the power lines entering the substation, I should place surge arresters on the power lines. Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surge arrestors the first line of defense in a switchyard. These surge arrestors are used to earth any lightning or switching surges that occur in the transmission line.

Typically, metal oxide surge arrestor (MOSA) is used in every single phase of a transmission line with a surge counter and a leakage meter as well to monitor the healthiness of the equipment.

Answer (score 1):

It's not enough.

Not only lightning arrestors for every line but ground field diversion with overhead ground wire and then lightning rods to create a 45 deg cone outside the substation are used. So that it does not attract lightning to the grid.

[image]  [ref](https://www.electricaltechnology.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Substation-lightning-protection.png)